# Visual C Webcam Capture

Tags: c#, vb.net, video, webcam, capture

I am on the newer side to visual studio and have been working on a webcam capture project first in VB before transitioning over to Visual C#.  I have been utilizing directshow library to do so, and have gotten mixed results.  I can capture the audio and video just fine, but the size of the avi/wmv file tends to be too large.  My goal file size is an hour of video/audio coming in at between 300 - 500 mb with the video quality being around 640x480 @ 15 fps.  I know I could use several compressors/codecs to shrink the size but most of the default system ones aren't really hitting my target.  I did notice that one of the samples in the DirectShow library CapWMV captures video in that target range, but it does not capture audio.  So my question is can anyone recommend an open-source codec that could help me hit that target or if someone is familiar with the CapWMV sample, explain how if possible audio capture could be incorporated into it?

Answer (score 0):

`CapWMV` can be upated to capture audio. You need to configure the writer there to set an audio-enabled profile and the writer will expose audio input to access audio stream. Because this is merely a wrapper over native API, you will need the documentation for underlying [WM ASF Writer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

CapWMV sample hardcodes a video-only profile:

```cs
    private IBaseFilter ConfigAsf(ICaptureGraphBuilder2 capGraph, string szOutputFileName)
    {
        // ...
            // Windows Media Video 8 for Dial-up Modem (No audio, 56 Kbps)
            // READ THE README for info about using guids
            Guid cat = new Guid(0x6E2A6955, 0x81DF, 0x4943, 0xBA, ...
```